# How to detect Android Application Boot/Launcher

Tags: android, android-broadcast

How to detect Android application launcher/boot?

And give some idea briefly.

I want to detect launcher application. which application is launcher i want to push my password screen after that it will go to application.. it's same app locker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
Toast.makeText(context, "Don't panik but your time is up!!!!.",
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
// Vibrate the mobile phone
Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
vibrator.vibrate(2000);
  }

}
```

and also pass intent filter in android manifest file

Comment: @Dear Kamal, which type of intent filter add to android manifest

Comment: its possible to call intent onReceive..give some idea

Comment: <receiver android:name=".Bootreceiver" android:enabled="true" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>

Comment: into this bootreceiver is my class and intent filter is in this

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html
read this article

Comment: ya ok i will read the pdf after that. i will check out

Comment: its possible detect application launcher.. the above code was detect os boot only... its not detect application boot. pls give some butter

Comment: yes bro it will run your app on boot , read that article everything is given in that file

Comment: add me on fb facebook.com/rimpv

Comment: OK KAMAL. THANKS LOTS.IF